# Копирование класса ячейки таблицы в такую же ячейку но строкой выше

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите решить такую вот задачу. У меня есть таблица. В которую динамически бекендом подгружаются  данные.  По клику на строке появляется еще одна строка ниже, где в процентах указывается изменения по каждой ячейке. В зависимости от положительной или негативной динамики цвет процентов зеленый или красный. Для этого добавляется класс green  или red.  Это то что есть, и то что работает!

Вот то что мне нужно сделать.

К каждой ячейке с помощью `::after`  я добавил небольшой кружок,  который должен быть окрашен в красный или зеленый цвет, как данные в скрытой строке.  По сути, мне нужно как-то проверить, какой класс  в каждой ячейке, в строке ниже и добавить классы ячейкам строки выше.  Для этого я создал классы `.green-circle` и `.red-circle`.  Я добавил эти классы некоторым ячейкам для наглядности. И создал пример. Но мне  нужно это делать динамически и у меня это никак не выходит. Мне также желательно совсем не менять структуру HTML, или делать это по минимуму.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'th:first-child', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(".hidden").toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th, tr {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

th {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

th:first-child {
  padding: 10px 60px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr:first-child th:first-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s;
}

.visible th::after {
  display: none;
}

.title th {
  position: relative;
}

.title th::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.title .green-circle::after {
  background: green;
}

.title .red-circle::after {
  background: red;
}

th:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.title-line:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 42px;
  top: 13px;
  background: transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #2b435c;
}

.title-line:first-child.active {
  color: #007bff;
}

.title-line:first-child.active::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tbody >
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>feb</th>
        <th>mar</th>
        <th>apr</th>
        <th>may</th>
        <th>jun</th>
        <th>jul</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>growmn rate</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="title">
        <th class="title-line">
            Active
        </th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>18%</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <th></th>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="title">
        <th class="title-line">
            Active2
        </th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th class="green-circle">6%</th>
        <th >90%</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <th></th>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="title">
        <th class="title-line">
            Active3
        </th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th class="red-circle">6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>1%</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <th></th>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const $container = $('.container'),
  $rowTitle = $container.find('tr.title');
  
$rowTitle.each(function() {
  const $row = $(this),
    $rowChildren = $row.children(),
    $nextRow = $row.next(),
    $nextRowChildren = $nextRow.children();
    
  $nextRowChildren.each(function(i) {
    const $cell = $(this);

    $rowChildren.eq(i)
      .toggleClass('green-circle', $cell.hasClass('green'))
      .toggleClass('red-circle', $cell.hasClass('red'));
  });

  $rowChildren.first().on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $nextRow.toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th, tr {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

th {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

th:first-child {
  padding: 10px 60px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr:first-child th:first-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s;
}

.visible th::after {
  display: none;
}

.title th {
  position: relative;
}

.title th::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.title .green-circle::after {
  background: green;
}

.title .red-circle::after {
  background: red;
}

th:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.title-line:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 42px;
  top: 13px;
  background: transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #2b435c;
}

.title-line:first-child.active {
  color: #007bff;
}

.title-line:first-child.active::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tbody >
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>feb</th>
        <th>mar</th>
        <th>apr</th>
        <th>may</th>
        <th>jun</th>
        <th>jul</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>growmn rate</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="title">
        <th class="title-line">
            Active
        </th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>18%</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <th></th>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="title">
        <th class="title-line">
            Active2
        </th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th >90%</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <th></th>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="title">
        <th class="title-line">
            Active3
        </th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>6%</th>
        <th>1%</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <th></th>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="red">50%</td>
        <td class="green">50%</td>
        <td class="green"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Все круто большое спасибо!  Единственное, мне нужно чтоб точки  еще до клика светились  нужными цветами.  Буду  вам очень благодарен!

Comment: Обновил в соответствии с новыми вводными

Comment: Это то! спасибо